# How to insert all C# object values to MySQL table in one query?

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

I have an object with many parameters, each represents a column in the MySQL table.

I have a code which generates a new object with all the above parameters and their values:

```
foreach (MetaData metaData in elnetMcMapping.DataItems) {
    var value = metaData.Value[0] * metaData.Multiplier;
    Type type = mcReadings.GetType();
    PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty(metaData.Label);
    prop.SetValue(mcReadings, value, null);
}
```

Now I want to insert all the values to the MySql table as a new row but not sure how to dynamically implement the below logic:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
await dataAccess.SaveData("insert into", mcReadings, DeviceDb);
```

Does anyone have a code example to help me with this ?

Comment: Parameterization of table and field names in RDBMS's like MySql is generally not allowed.  You're better off using a single table, adding a column specifying your `mcReading` name or type, and then writing a query that filters on your desired name or type for data retrieval.

Comment: If you need more flexibility than that, store your data as JSON objects.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The above will require major refactoring at this stage, I'm surprised to hear there are no Nuget packages to handle this kind of task, seems like a common issue

Comment: Seems like an [X Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something like the following:

```cs
// Build the SQL statement, this can be cached and used again
var propList = mcReadings.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.Append("INSERT INTO elnet21630388 (");
// Build column list
foreach(PropertyInfo prop in propList) 
{
    str.Append(prop.Name + ",");
}
str.Remove(str.Length - 1, 1);
str.Append(") VALUES (");
// Build values list
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in propList) 
{ 
    str.Append("@" + prop.Name + ",");
}
str.Remove(str.Length - 1, 1);
str.Append(");");

// Generate the dynamic parameters, this needs to be done on each call 
DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in propList)
{
    parameters.Add("@" + prop.Name, prop.GetValue(mcReadings, null));
}

connection.Execute(str.ToString(), parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var propList = mcReadings.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.Append("INSERT INTO elnet21630388 (");
foreach(PropertyInfo prop in propList) {str.Append(prop.Name + ",");}
str.Remove(str.Length - 1, 1);
str.Append(") VALUES (");
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in propList) { str.Append(prop.GetValue(mcReadings).ToString() + ","); }
str.Remove(str.Length - 1, 1);
str.Append(");");
```

Comment: Now you won't get the advantage of parameterized queries. It's better to build a list of Dapper's DynamicParameter, assign values and build the query as you do now, but with @ in front of the parameter names. You can even cache this for performance.

Comment: @PalleDue thank you for the tip, do you mean I should loop something like this: m.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("param1", val1));

Comment: I've added an answer to show what I mean.